# Necesito que un guion php que tiene una lista mysql, envie id a otro guion php

Tags: php, html, mysql

¿Cómo puedo enviar esta id mysql a otra etiqueta php?, debo enviar la id de una tabla a un modal de la misma pagina para sacar el trabajo con esa id pero no se como.

Este es mi codigo:

**MODAL**

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" id="preview" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myExtraLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content">

 <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Trabajo</h5>


      </div>
<div class="modal-body">
<?php
include("../../conexion.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM codigos WHERE id = $id";
$resultado = $conexion -> query($query);
while($row = $resultado -> fetch_assoc()){
?>
    <?php echo $row['trabajo'];?>
    <?php 
     }
    ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**TABLA**

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
      <th scope="col">Trabajo</th>
      <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
      <th scope="col">Acción</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
include("../../conexion.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM codigos";
$resultado = $conexion -> query($query);
while($row = $resultado -> fetch_assoc()){
?>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo $row['id'];?></th>
      <td><?php echo $row['nombre'];?></td>
      <td><a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="$('#preview').modal(); <?php $id = echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-success">Ver</a></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['fecha'];?></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Calificar</a><a href="borrar_codigo.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a></td>

    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Necesito que al presionar el botón **ver** envíe la id de donde se presionó al PHP del modal para que se abra el modal con el trabajo. pero necesito que no deba recargar o actualizar la pagina y que se pueda reutilizar ya que quiero que si presiona otro botón **ver** salga el modal con el otro trabajo.
¿Me pueden ayudar?.
Nota: Los 2 codigos son de la misma pagina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza ajax invocandolo desde un evento onclik

ejemplo:
en tu td de tu lista agrega una clase ver y un atributo id

```
<td><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="ver" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-success">Ver</a></td>
```

y el evento de tu ajax de la siguiente manera:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ver', function(event){
        var id=parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
        //peticion ajax
        $.ajax({                                      
        url: "consulta.php"
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id:id},
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res){
            if(res.error==0){//puedes regresar un valor de error pos si ocurre 
                $('.modal .modal-body').html(res.view_result);//contenedor

            }
            else
                $('.modal .modal-body').html("ocurrio un error en mi operacion backend");
             $('.modal').modal("show");//muestras el modal

        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
              $('.modal .modal-body').html("error:"+XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
              $('.modal').modal("show");
        }
        });
    });
```

en tu codigo de consulta.php

```
<?php
include("../../conexion.php");
$id=$_POST["id"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM codigos WHERE id = $id";
$resultado = $conexion -> query($query);
$htmlcontenidomodal="";
$msg="";//variable para asignar mensaje donde ocurra un error en la operaciones a realizar ya sea en la conexion o en la consulta, etc.
while($row = $resultado -> fetch_assoc()){
    $htmlcontenidomodal.="";//aqui va los datos que mostraras en tu contenidode tu modal
}

$respuesta=array("error"=>0,"msg"=>$msg,"view_result"=>$htmlcontenidomodal);
echo json_encode($respuesta);
?>
```

Comment: lo de **....aqui va tu consulta para llenar tu contenido en la variable $htmlcontenidomodal ** es para la variable $id?

Comment: va el resultado de tu consulta, checa la respuesta lo he actualizado en la parte de php

Comment: al dar click al boton ver, la pagina se detiene completamente, ¿hize algo mal?

Comment: revisa si esta entrando al evento click con un console.log o un alert()

Comment: Si ya revise y funcionan el evento click y el success

Comment: revisa que te esta regresando valores en success y tambien verifica si $('.modal').modal("show") funciona

Comment: Si me regresa el evento success y lo del modal show no puedo verificar ya que la página se queda congelada al dar click en ver

Comment: checa que contiene res en function(res), puede ser que en tu dodigo php este el problema

Comment: Qué contiene res? Cómo?

Comment: si revisa si res.view_result trae algun valor

Comment: No, no regresa nada

Comment: he modificado el codigo en la respuesta en la parte de success y error para que detectes que puede estar pasando,

Comment: ya funciona pero cuando abre el modal sucede algo raro, sale el modal con una especie de cuadro que sale del modal

Comment: puede que sea problema del diseño ya sea por una etiqueta que no se este cerrando o el contenido

Comment: ya solucione el error, en lugar de abrir un modal estaba abriendo todos ya que estaba abriendo por nombre de clase y lo configure a id que es "preview", pero cuando lo abre no muestra nada

Comment: revisa si en tu codigo php si esta accediendo a los datos de tu base, si tienes un while checa si esta entrando en caso que si este entrando codifica tus valores a utf8 ya que puede ser que los valores contengan acentos

Comment: Ya funciono!!!!!!!! gracias, era un problema que yo cometi estaba confundiendo las filas de la base da datos graciaaas

Comment: me surgio una duda. veras que aparte del boton ver hay un boton que dice calificar. como hago que al apretar el boton guarde el id como en el boton ver  y lance el modal pero en lugar de mostrar algo solo se quede guardada, ya que en el modal quiero poner una input-number donde pondra la calificacion y que al apretar un boton dentro del modal recoja el numero escrito para mandarlo a la consulta y actualize la calificacion de la base de datos???